# Store huge data

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a lot of data, something like 300 x 68k points stored as double, it represents magnetic field and I need this points in my Android app. But it is something like 80MB and I think this is enormous data, writing it in table wouldn't be really efficient. So I have a question: how should I store it to have access to this data in really fast way? Fast, I mean ms.

Comment: This all should be stored as one entity or individual entity ??

Comment: We have divided building for 5 parts but I don't know if loading 1 part of data wouldn't last too long if a user switch his position to another part of a building. 1 part is something like 3 meteres x 20 meteres.

Comment: You could try to use Realm.

Comment: This still doesn't provide sufficient information on how you want to store, based on that only answer can be provided on best mechanism .. For example, BLOBs are used for large storage, but I am not recommending it for now ..

Comment: But I don't know how I want to store the data, this is my question. We read values from the magnetic sensor and we search for this value in our data. So I think it shouldn't be written in an array, because of the size. So my question is, where I should keep my data to have a really quick access to it

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques I've searched for Realm, thank you. But is it really fast? Or you have an idea, how can I improve searching?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Realm.

[image]

Looks like the best approach.

Reference: https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm/

Comment: Please, don't forget to let me know. Good luck.

Comment: I have built my database with Realm, but cannot use it in my another app. I'd be grateful if you can take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001760/import-prepopulated-realm-database