# Import prepopulated Realm database

Tags: android, realm

I have prepopulated realm database, so I have default.realm. I want to use it in another app so I put it  in my \res\raw folder. I read that it should be as easy as calling Realm.getInstance(). I have code like this:

```
copyBundledRealmFile(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.default0), "default.realm");

realm = Realm.getInstance(this);

private String copyBundledRealmFile(InputStream inputStream, String outFileName) {
        try {
            File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), outFileName);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            return file.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I can see a default.realm in my app package, so I think copyBundledRealmFile was executed, but then io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException occurs. I don't know if there is a way to skip migration part? Because I think I don't actually migrate, just use prepopulated databse. And writing Migration part won't be as easy as calling Realm.getInstance().

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. The bundled database is getting copied correctly. `RealmMigrationNeededException` means that the `RealmObject` subclasses that you defined in your project and the structure of the bundled realm file doesn't exactly match. Check and make sure that the database table columns defined in the bundled realm file and in the model classes match (name, data type, nullability).

Comment: Hmmm, I'm pretty sure they should match, because I just copy-paste from one app(which was populating database) to the second app, which I'm using right now.

Comment: Do these two apps share the exact same sets of model classes without any omissions of classes, modifications to class names, properties and their types?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 classes, "Row" and "Value" and i copied and pasted them in the new app. The only difference is, they were in package "database" or something like this and now they're in the main package. Does it make any difference? And if it is needed, I can paste here both app most important classes.

Comment: If you have more than two classes in the generating app, you have to have the same number of classes in the other app. If you don't need the other classes, you can use a `RealmModule` - see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/moduleExample

Comment: @meDarq have you find the solution of your problem ,i am also facing the same issue

Comment: @justchill No, not really. Actualy, I even don't remember this problem very well.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced with the same problem. But the issue was in my model definition. I made it manually.

Try to open the database in Realm Browser and Save Model Definition for Java. I did it and it fixed the issue.